# Current value displayed in ComboBox

Tags: mvvm, wpf-controls, caliburn.micro

I can't seem to get the current selected value to show in the ComboBox when the items in the ComboBox are custom objects from the database.  I put together the following test ViewModel and View.  SimpleWidgets and ObjectWidgets behave as expected.  CodeWidgets (list retrieved from the database as custom 'Code' objects) never displays the SelectedCodeWidget.

```cs
    public class TestViewModel:BaseTabViewModel
    {
    private List<int> simpleWidgets;
    public List<int> SimpleWidgets
    {
        get { return simpleWidgets; }
        set
        {
            simpleWidgets = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SimpleWidgets);
        }
    }

    private int selectedSimpleWidget;
    public int SelectedSimpleWidget
    {
        get { return selectedSimpleWidget; }
        set
        {
            selectedSimpleWidget = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedSimpleWidget);
        }
    }

    private List<Widget> objectWidgets;
    public List<Widget> ObjectWidgets
    {
        get { return objectWidgets; }
        set
        {
            objectWidgets = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ObjectWidgets);
        }
    }

    private Widget _selectedObjectWidget;
    public Widget SelectedObjectWidget
    {
        get { return _selectedObjectWidget; }
        set
        {
            _selectedObjectWidget = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedObjectWidget);
        }
    }

    private List<ICode> codeWidgets;
    public List<ICode> CodeWidgets
    {
        get { return codeWidgets; }
        set
        {
            codeWidgets = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CodeWidgets);
        }
    }
    private Code _selectedCodeWidget;
    public Code SelectedCodeWidget
    {
        get { return _selectedCodeWidget; }
        set
        {
            _selectedCodeWidget = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedCodeWidget);
        }
    }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "Test Data";
        IsEnabled = true;//control this with permissions
        //Simple int comboBox
        SimpleWidgets = new List<int> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        SelectedSimpleWidget = 7;
        //Object filled ComboBox
        ObjectWidgets= new List<Widget>();
        Widget w = new Widget {Key = 2, Description = "test2"};
        ObjectWidgets.Add(w);
        w = new Widget { Key = 4, Description = "test4" };
        ObjectWidgets.Add(w);
        w = new Widget {Key = 6, Description = "test6"};
        ObjectWidgets.Add(w);
        SelectedObjectWidget = w;
        //Code filled ComboBox
        CodeWidgets = (new Code().Get("UPFLTY").Result).ToList();
        SelectedCodeWidget = new Code(2707);
    }
}

public class Widget
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The TestView.xaml is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CAB.DataManager.App.Views.TestView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UniformGrid>

        <ComboBox Name="SimpleWidgets"></ComboBox>
            <ComboBox Name="ObjectWidgets"
                     DisplayMemberPath="Description" >
             </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="CodeWidgets">
                 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </UniformGrid>
</UserControl>
```

SimpleWidgets and ObjectWidgets show the selected value and have all values in the dropdown.  CodeWidgets is blank but does have all values in the dropdown. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *instance* that is in `SelectedItem` **must exist within** `ItemsSource`.

From your code

```cs
//Code filled ComboBox
CodeWidgets = (new Code().Get("UPFLTY").Result).ToList();
SelectedCodeWidget = new Code(2707); // THIS is where you bugged!
```

You can see that `SelectedCodeWidget` is set to a new instance of `Code`, one that is not in `CodeWidgets`.

The answer is simply to do the following:

```cs
//Code filled ComboBox
CodeWidgets = (new Code().Get("UPFLTY").Result).ToList();
var selectedCode = FindCodeByDERP(CodeWidgets, 2707); // MAKE THIS METHOD
SelectedCodeWidget = selectedCode;
```

Where `FindCodeByDERP` is a method you write that searches through the instances in `CodeWidgets` and returns the instance which **2707**s the hardest.  Whatever that means.  I mean, you've got a Code *UPFLTY* yet you create another instance passing in *2707*... that makes no sense.  Yeah.

Answer (score 4):

WPF's ComboBox compares the SelectedItem to the ones in the ItemsSource by reference, and in your case the instance of `new Code(2707)` is not the exact same instance in memory as whatever is in `(new Code().Get("UPFLTY").Result).ToList()`

The most common way to avoid this is to use `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` on something that has a generic object type instead.

For example,

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CodeWidgets" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCodeId}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Id">
```

Another solution is to ensure the SelectedItem is set to one of the items in the ItemsSource, and not a new instance of the item.

```cs
SelectedCodeWidget = CodeWidgets.FirstOrDefault(() => p.Id == 2707);
```

And the third solution, not usually recommend, is to override the `.Equals` of your object so it compares the item by something other than reference

```cs
public override bool Equals(object obj) 
{ 
    if (obj == null || !(obj is Code)) 
        return false; 

    return ((Code)obj).Id == this.Id); 
}
```

Note that you should probably also overwrite `.GetHashCode()` if you go this route too.