# Displaying a selected ComboBox Item in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to construct a ComboBox that will display a selected item. I can get the combo box to display the options easily enough, but getting the selected item to display is not working. The selected item refers to a value being pulled from a database.

I know that the set method is working because I can successfully store the user's choice. However, I cannot seem to get the ComboBox to populate the selected item when I grab it from the database.

I've been frustrated over this for a few weeks now, and I feel like the mistake is simple.

***Scenario:***

**I have an `Animal Model`**

```
public class AnimalModel
{
    public string AnimalName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**I have an `AnimalViewModel` for each `Animal`:**

```
public class AnimalViewModel: BindableBase
{
    private AnimalViewModel _animal;

    public AnimalViewModel(AnimalModel animal)
    {
        _animal = animal;
    }

    public string AnimalName
    {
        get { return _animal.Name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._animal.Name)
            {
                this._animal.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AnimalName");
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**I have an `ObservableCollection` of `AnimalViewModel` objects:**

```
public class TemplateViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<AnimalViewModel> _animals;
    public TemplateViewModel(...)
    {
        _animal = methodReturnsAnObservableCollectionOfAnimalViewModels();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AnimalViewModel> Animals
    {
        get { return _animals; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._animals)
            {
                this._animals = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Animals");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this in place, I can easily display a list of `AnimalName`s in the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="AnimalName" 
          IsEditable="True" 
          IsReadOnly="True" 
          Text="--- Select Animal ---"/>
```

**I now bind to a SelectedItem**

```
public class TemplateViewModel
{
    ...
    private AnimalViewModel _selectedAnimal;
    public TemplateViewModel(MyObject, ...)
    {
        ...
        _selectedAnimal = new AnimalViewModel(new AnimalModel() { AnimalName = MyObject.AnimalName });
    }
    ...
    public AnimalViewModel SelectedAnimal
    {
        get { return _selectedAnimal; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedAnimal)
            {
                _selectedAnimal = value;
                AnimalName = value.AnimalName;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAnimal");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now, I have:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="AnimalName" 
          SelectedItem={Binding SelectedAnimal} 
          SelectedValuePath="AnimalName" 
          IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" 
          Text="--- Select Animal ---"/>
```

Unfortunately, this does not populate the ComboBox with an Animal. It just pulls up the default choice `Select Animal` with the options populated. It *does* set the item correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I answered a question just like this yesterday [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31415361/302677). Same answer applies :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the actual `reference` to the animal in question.

In the codebehind you create an *animal* which looks like the animal in the ObservableCollection, but its not the animal by *reference*.

Change (*after Animals is loaded*)

```
 _selectedAnimal = new AnimalViewModel(...);
```

to  (*only use the Property accessor, not the backing store variable; so the change event fires, btw*)

```
SelectedAnimal = Animals[0];
```

---

Test app (formatting like grid row/column removed)

```
<Label>SelectedItem</Label>
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cbMain}"/>
<Label >SelectedValue</Label>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=cbMain}"/>
<Button  Click="ChangeSelectedValue">Set Selected Value</Button>
<ComboBox Name="cbMain"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Ships}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Ships[0]}"
            SelectedValuePath="Name"
            Text="Select a Ship"/>
```

Result on Load of screen:

[image]

Comment: So, I completely get the logic behind passing the `reference` to the object, and I feel a dull for not catching that. That being said, even when I pass by reference and initialize the property accessor, I still can't seem to get the selected value to display. Set is still working, but I'm really frustrated with this get method.

Comment: Also, I feel like I have some other conceptual error. If I want to get the index, I should be able to do something like `_animals.IndexOf(new AnimalViewModel(new AnimalModel { Name = myobject.name }))` But object is not found in the collection. I get `-1`.

Comment: @Bryant Try removing the `SelectedValuePath`.... that should only be used if you're binding the selected item with `SelectedValue`, which you are not.

Comment: @Bryant As for your 2nd comment, `IndexOf` also compares items by reference so of course the reference of a new instance of `AnimalViewModel` is not going to exist in `_animals`. You want something like `_animals.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == myObject.name)`, which translates into *"find the first item in this collection where the `.Name` property is equal to `myObject.name`"*

Comment: @Rachel I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. Even without `SelectedValuePath`, nothing occurs. I feel like I've tried every variant. Even setting `SelectedAnimal = _animals[0]` or `= Animals[0]` just doesn't work. Whether I use the backing variable, the property, ensure it's passing the reference. It just doesn't set at all.

Comment: @Bryant I created a test app with *ship* list (not observable collection) which used the `SelectedItem="{Binding Ships[0]}"` in the binding and it worked. I can't see why an observable collection is coming into play...One thought. Maybe step away from your current code base and create a test project which may show the differences. ??

Comment: @Bryant The code works fine for me once I switch to setting the selected item by reference. My best guess is that the .AnimialName property of the selected item is being changed to *"--- Select Animal ---"* because of the way your setters are implemented. The line of code `AnimalName = value.AnimalName;` in the setter of your TemplateViewModel looks very out of place. Can you do a test a runtime to verify that the Animals collection contains the SelectedItem after loading?

Comment: Finally fixed. I ended up adding a `select an item` option to the list instead of trying to rig it in wpf, since it seems to override the setter. @OmegaMan Did your text property work?

Comment: @Bryant, Oddly enough, no. I checked the documentation on MSDN,  [Combobox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx), and the example shows the `Text` property being  set with a "Select this" kind of text, but the documentation never mentions it. When I run the sample nothing shows. If it is run with no items, nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a naming discrepancy between `SelectedValuePath="AnimalName"` and your property.

```
public string Animal //<----Should Be AnimalName!
{
    get { return _animal.Name; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this._animal.Name)
        {
            this._animal.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AnimalName");
        }
    }
}
```

change your property to AnimalName and you're good to go.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I typed it in SO. Still no luck.